# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is piece of code i am getting an error in the console, can anyone point out where i am doing it wrong ? thanks in advance.

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    // every 4 seconds execute following
    var visibleWord = document.getElementsByClassName('visible')[0],
    nextWord = visibleWord.nextSibling;

    // check if nextSibling is textnode (whitespace) - if so get next next sibling. 
    if (nextWord.nodeType == 3) nextWord = nextWord.nextSibling;

    // if there is a next node 
    if (!(nextWord == null)) {
        visibleWord.setAttribute('class', 'hidden');
        nextWord.setAttribute('class', 'visible');
    } else {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
}, 4000)
```

Comment: check for null/undefined before accessing nextSibling

Comment: _"check if nextSibling is textnode (whitespace) - if so get next next sibling"_ -> [.nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the element you are looking for (with class `visible`) is not existing when the code is ran. Maybe you are running the code too early (before DOM is parsed).

Try adding simple if condition like this:

```
var visibleWord = document.getElementsByClassName('visible')[0];

if (!visibleWord) {
    return;
}

// continue with the code... 
var nextWord = visibleWord.nextSibling;
```

Answer (score 0):

is means there is no `visibleWord` so if that is the case you could return like so:

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
// every 4 seconds execute following
var visibleWord = document.getElementsByClassName('visible')[0],
    if(null == visibleWord) {    // added this line
        return;                  // and this line
    }                            // and this line
    nextWord = visibleWord.nextSibling;
// check if nextSibling is textnode (whitespace) - if so get next next sibling. 
if (nextWord.nodeType == 3) nextWord = nextWord.nextSibling;
// if there is a next node 
if (!(nextWord == null)) {
    visibleWord.setAttribute('class', 'hidden');
    nextWord.setAttribute('class', 'visible');
} else {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
}
}, 4000)
```